# Graph api get facebook app data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I was wondering if it's possible to get data from apps, such as discussions or extended info through Graph api or FQL? I'm using the PHP sdk, though it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Feel free to make an answer with your findings (even if it's just "this isn't possible") and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible. Can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what you exactly want..

But I think if you need information related to app there is a graph api available for this, please refer the documentation from the following link,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

The feed connections of application graph object could get the feed for the application..

If you are not looking for this, can you explain a bit further about what you need exactly.

Comment: I'll take a look at it and see if it's what I was looking for. Like discussions I wanted to get the list of discussions, and the posts on each disussion. And for say Extended Info, I wanted just to pull the different info's(I don't know what you would call them).Like if there was one that said "Favorite hobbie" - "Tennis".

Answer (score 0):

To get posts and comments from wall of some Facebook application [you may test here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) following FQL query

```
SELECT 
post_id, viewer_id, message, app_id, source_id, 
created_time, updated_time, filter_key, attribution,
actor_id, target_id, message, app_data, action_links, 
attachment, impressions, comments, likes, privacy, 
permalink, xid, tagged_ids, message_tags, description_tags 
FROM stream WHERE 
source_id = {ID_of_wall_of_your_App}
```

where url of my app's wall is as follows:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/display_name/ID_of_wall_of_your_App#!/pages/display_name/ID_of_wall_of_your_App?sk=wall

I'll make one more an update later.

Comment: The Discussion and Extended Info apps aren't mine

Comment: Thanks, I understand what the query does, but it looks like the discussion app doesn't post to the wall.